# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'THEN'

Tags: sql, sql-server, boolean

Can anyone explain to me this behaviour in SQL Server.
I've got an UPDATE statement as part of a stored proc, and it get a 'An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'THEN' error in some cases as per below.  First the statement.

```
UPDATE MyDB.dbo.OrganisationUnits
SET OrganisationUnit = Inserted.OrganisationUnit,
ParentOrganisationUnit = 
    (CASE WHEN ((SELECT Count(1) 
                 FROM [172.24.112.10].Consurgo.dbo.OrganisationUnits CO1
                 WHERE CO1.OrganisationUnit = Inserted.ParentOrganisationUnit) = 1)
          THEN Inserted.ParentOrganisationUnit
          ELSE CO.ParentOrganisationUnit
END),
OrganisationLevel = Inserted.OrganisationLevel
FROM Inserted, Deleted, MyDB.dbo.OrganisationUnits CO
WHERE CO.OrganisationUnit = Deleted.OrganisationUnit
```

The error comes in in the CASE statement at the ' = 1' part.

As the statement is now, it works.  If I change the =1 part to > 0 then it fails with error message above.

With <> 0 it also fails.  But with <> 1 it works.

It also works with =2 and <>2.

Comment: What happens if you replace Count(1) by Count(CO1) ?

Comment: I get: Invalid column name 'CO1'.

Comment: There's no obvious reason why comparisons with zero should fail but comparisons with non-zero should work.  That suggests that you may be hitting an idiosyncrasy (aka _bug_) in the version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: I cannot repro this: `SELECT  ParentOrganisationUnit = (CASE WHEN ((SELECT COUNT (1) FROM sys.objects) = 1) THEN 1
                                       ELSE 0
                                  END)
FROM    sys.objects`

Comment: Sorry, I meant Count(*) or Count(CO1.OrganisationUnit)

Comment: Can you create a simple repro? Try using catalog tables and stripping away unnecessary stuff.

Comment: I suspect a problem with your linked server. Is that `OrganisationUnits` a view or have a calculated column?

Comment: Both the servers have a table OrganisationUnits (not a view) with no calculated columns.  I guess a 'bug' is probably an acceptable answer.

Comment: Count(*) and Count(CO1.OrganisationUnit) gives the same error as Count(1).